# Python : Call list attribute from a list of defined attributes

Tags: python

I have a list with list operations, For example `["insert", "append"]`, For now I am doing like if list says insert then I am calling `.insert`.

Check below code

```py
In [31]: list_ops = [ "insert" , "append" ]

In [32]: list1 = [ 1 , 3 , 5 ]

In [33]: if list_ops[0] == "insert" :
    ...:     list1.insert(3, 7)
    ...:

In [34]: list1
Out[34]: [1, 3, 5, 7]

In [35]: list1.list_ops[0](4, 9 )
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-5db0dcceeac1> in <module>
----> 1 list1.list_ops[0](4, 9 )

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'list_ops'

In [36]:
```

How can I choose the operation from `list_ops` itself instead of doing if-else matching.

Thank you.

Comment: im pretty sure you cant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't choose an operation from `list_ops`, because it's a list of strings, not of operations.  You need to choose the operation *based* on the string.  For instance:

```
list_ops = {
    "insert": list.insert,
    "append": list.append
}
```

Now you can choose the operation based on the input string.  Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) and f-Strings if you really wanted to do it:

```py
operation = "append"
list1 = [1, 2, 3]

exec(f"list1.{operation}(4)")
print(list1) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But to be honest, I think it's a better idea to create an operation dictionary like Prune suggested.